# Angular Material autocomplete 's mat-option with two searchable value

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm new to angular and I have a mat-autocomplete as search field 
and I want each of my mat-option to be searchable with 2 value for example with a name and with an id:

```
options = [{name: 'x', id: 123},{name: 'y', id:142}]
```

any body know how I can do that?

Comment: I didn't use material library but as I can see you can put ``mat-option`` inside ``mat-autocomplete`` - so how about looping through names and ids?

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the Angular Material Autocomplete [examples](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples), especially the one called **Filter autocomplete** you will see how the filtering is done and you can easily extend it to filter multiple values.

From the example (keep in mind here the `options` array is just an array of strings, so no properties are accessed/filtered):

```
private _filter(value: string): string[] {
  const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
  return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
}
```

We could rewrite this to the following to filter an additional `id` attribute (assuming `options` is an array of objects with the properties `name` and `id`):

```
private _filter(value: string): Option[] {
  const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
  return this.options.filter(option => String(option.id).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue ) > -1 || 
  option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue ) > -1);
}
```

> [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-8nsvov?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)
>   is a stackblitz showing the filtering mentioned above.

Comment: This just saved me hours. Many thanks for the explanatory answer. @Fabian Kung